# Removing arrays from superglobals ($_GET, $_POST...)

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP it's possible to have arrays in `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_FILES` and `$_REQUEST` according to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). The problem is that those come from user and I might get them instead of strings. For example, consider following snippet.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    echo 'Hello, ', htmlspecialchars($_GET['hello']), '.';
}
else {
    echo '<form action="?"><input name="hello"><input type="submit"></form>';
}
```

Looks OK? Well, as long you will not work will the URL it will work correctly. The problem is that hacker can try making `$_GET['hello']` an array. If URL string looks like `?hello[]=something` PHP will return error message

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in FILE on line 3

OK, who would enable in HTML errors in the production site (the other thing is error log...). But integers also are a problem - PHP is dynamically typed language, so it would accept easily code like `'2' + 2`. While yes, you can use `(int)` I have some old code which doesn't do that. If string comes from `$_GET` or `$_POST` it could be also array. Something like `array('2') + 2` would cause fatal error of PHP.

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in FILE on line 3

Now it's something that isn't acceptable because it would stop the script. I don't need arrays in those variables, but they annoy me. Is there any simple snippet which would remove arrays from those special variables. If I really would want an array, I could make copy of it before running the snippet.

Comment: Just validate them before using. You can put extra checks there like `is_array` to check if the supplied variable is array, escaping them etc.

Comment: Truth be told, who cares?  If you're validating worth a damn, then the most that happens is you don't do anything.

Comment: @glitchMr guy, im the one from chat room, i got suspended please contact me via contact section on live-pin.com. thanks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if it was a string before using it in a string context.

```
$name = (isset($_GET['name']) && is_string($_GET['name'])) ? $_GET['name'] : 'Unknown!';
```

Or:

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) && is_string($_GET['name']) {
    //do stuff
}
```

If you wanted to remove all arrays though:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        unset($_GET[$key]);
    }
}
```

Oops look like Sudhir already beat me to that part, but already had it typed... :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `is_array()` to check for such a thing.

```
if (is_array($_GET['hello']) // exit/error
```

or just display the form again

```
if (isset($_GET['hello']) && !is_array($_GET['hello']) {
```

As for someone inputting something like  `array('2') + 2` you don't need to worry much.  It's already a string, therefor it won't be run as php script.  However, depending on your scope is always a good idea to encode the information in a format best for you.

In you example, someone could inject HTML code into your get variable, causing the site to look different.  Simple functions like `strip_tags` or `htmlentities` wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You forgot to close a bracket at the end of the if. Other than that, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you then do something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps in some sense.